# symfony: trying to give a value to a modified 'id' field

Tags: symfony1, propel

I'm trying to give different attributes to the field id (as you know if you write "id: ~") the field id is autoincrementable and a primary key).

So I have write this:

```
  nations:
    primary_key:                        { type: INTEGER, size: 5, required: true, primaryKey: true}
    id:                                 { type: INTEGER, size: 5, required: true, primaryKey: false}
    name:                               { type: VARCHAR, size: 64 }
    iso_code_2:                         { type: CHAR, size: 2 }
    iso_code_3:                         { type: CHAR, size: 2 }
```

But when i try to load this fixture below i get this error:

```
  Cannot insert a value for auto-increment primary key (nations.ID)
```

This is the fixture:

```
Nations:
  france:
    id: '74'
    iso_code_2: FR
    iso_code_3: fr
```

So any way to force the loading of this fixture?

sf 1.4/propel

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. The following works for me in 1.4/Propel, but this does use ID (non-autoincrement) as PK. The fact that your error calls nations.ID a PK field makes it sound like a bug.

```
id:
  type: integer
  primaryKey: true
  required: true
```

Comment: Perhaps try reversing primary_key and id in the schema.yml?